# add icon to particular rows in django template table

Tags: python, css, django, icons

I am working on python Django templates in which I have a table having column as **id, factor A, factor B, factor C**. Values for id, factor A, factor B and factor C respectively are 79, 0.56, 1.1, 1.3.

[image]

The code for the html template is like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">id</th>
      <th class="text-center">Factor A</th>
      <th class="text-center">Factor B</th>
      <th class="text-center">Factor C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr ng-class="{'info':aggregateData.Mode, 'closed':!aggregateData.Open}">
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.id}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.factor_a}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.factor_b}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.factor_c}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table
```

I want to add a clickable icon to this similar like this for rows having **aggregateData.Open** true.
[image]

Can someone suggest a way how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">id</th>
      <th class="text-center">Factor A</th>
      <th class="text-center">Factor B</th>
      <th class="text-center">Factor C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr ng-class="{'info':aggregateData.Mode, 'closed':!aggregateData.Open}">
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.id}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.factor_a}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.factor_b}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{aggregateData.factor_c}}</td>
      {% if aggregateData.open == True %}
        <td class="text-center">
          <a href="https://www.google.co.in">
            <img src="/path_toicon.png">    
          </a>
        </td>
      {% endif %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```